# Does SES support AWS Signature V4 when using the REST API?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I see a lot of existing code bases that use the v3 signing api for SES, and didn't see SES on the v4 list. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_support.html

But I can't imagine why it wouldn't be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Amazon Simple Email Service does support Signature V4 signing. For example, the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet45/Amazon.SimpleEmail/AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.cs#L46), the [AWS SDK for Ruby V2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/apis/SES.api.json#L7), and the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-apis/blob/master/apis/email-2010-12-01.api.json#L7) use V4 signing.